# How to use Chrome's "Copy as cURL" for multipart/form-data post requests on Windows?

Tags: windows, forms, curl, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a module for a web application. To trigger this module, I need to submit some data to the server. For simple forms, `Copy as cURL` in the Chrome Developer Tools works fine (using curl from msys[git]), but for post requests with `multipart/form-data`, the copied string is neither usable in the windows shell (cmd) nor with bash (form msys); the copied text is similar to:

```
curl "http://myserver.local" -H "Origin: http://wiki.selfhtml.org" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryntXdlWbYXAVwCIMU" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Referer: http://wiki.selfhtml.org/extensions/Selfhtml/frickl.php/Beispiel:HTML_form-Element1.html" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-binary "------WebKitFormBoundaryntXdlWbYXAVwCIMU"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""area"""^

"multi"^
"line"^
"------WebKitFormBoundaryntXdlWbYXAVwCIMU--"^
"" --compressed
```

Is there any way I could use this or convert it to something usable?

Comment: Shouldn't there be another `^` at the blank line?

Comment: Unfortunately neither with nor without the `^` this command is interpreted as one command (tried with`cmd` and `bash`).

Comment: I suggest to create a bug report at https://crbug.com/new and tell the team that the Copy as cURL command is unusable on Windows. Let me know when you've created the ticket.

Comment: I hope, my description in https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=505391 is ok.

Comment: Nice bug report. It'd be nice if you also attach a screenshot that shows what actually happens.

Answer (score 32):

Chrome, as well as the other browsers actually, do a rather poor job of translating multi-part formposts into curl command lines.

A much more convenient curl command line would not use `--data-binary` for that, it would use `--form`. And then you want one `--form` per input field.

In your case, it *probably* would look something like (backslashes inserted here
for visibility):

```
curl "http://myserver.local" \
 --compressed \
 -H "Origin: http://wiki.selfhtml.org" \
 -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36" \
 -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" \
 -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" \
 -e "http://wiki.selfhtml.org/extensions/Selfhtml/frickl.php/Beispiel:HTML_form-Element1.html" \
 -F area=[contents]
```

I left the [contents] in there, but it should be replaced with what you actually want in the `area` field. You could also pass it from a file if you prefer to.

I removed two unnecessary `-H` uses, and I replaced two to use the direct curl options.

## h2c - headers to curl

Advice for the future: figure out the exact HTTP header trace you want to reproduce with a curl command line and paste it over at https://curl.se/h2c/ .

Comment: You got a down-vote for replying on a 5 years old question. The chrome developer fixed this bug about 5 years ago.

Comment: Additionally your answer did not met the requirements - I wanted to replay a call to the backend like it was done by the browser. I did not want to create a modified version of the call.

Comment: You do realise this is, uh, the creator of curl

Comment: 1. **Chrome has not** fixed this, not even in the latest version today five years later.
2. my version of the command line *does* send the same request, what would the point be otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

While [Daniel Stenberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62659224) is obviously the best, as web developers we don't always have time to manually create dozens of curl requests per day. And if we don't, Chrome's Copy as cURL can still fail for file uploads.

Laravel's `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::getClientMimeType()` isn't detecting the mime type for me. Xdebug for `$request->file->getMimeType()` just shows `application/x-empty`. Here's how a multipart form field for `my file.pdf` looks:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="my file.pdf"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

I've tried everything I can think of, like `filename="my file.pdf"; Content-Type: application/pdf` and combining Chrome's Copy as cURL with `-F "file=@Sample Estimated Fees.pdf;type=application/pdf"`. But cURL doesn't accept `-F` alongside `--data-raw` or it errors with:

```
Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST 
Warning: (-d, --data) and multipart formpost (-F, --form).
```

Instead of waiting around for curl to let us add `-F` parameters to the request body with the multipart/form-data boundary we specify, or Chrome to get fixed (unlikely to happen now that Google is playing catch-up to Bing's ChatGPT), we can use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) or its [web version](https://web.postman.co/home) (requires signup, which has privacy implications):

1. Chrome -> Developer Tools (web inspector) -> Network -> right click request -> Copy -> Copy as cURL
2. Open Postman
3. Click the `Import` button at top-left
4. Click the `Raw Text` tab
5. Paste
6. Click the `Continue` button
7. Click the `Import` button
8. Click the `</>` button at top-right to show Code snippet
9. Click the `⎘` button at top-right or copy the snippet manually

The new snippet is all but guaranteed to work on your platform, just note that the file **must** be present in the same directory where you're running curl. Bonus:

1. Click the `Body` tab -> `Bulk Edit` to get key-value pairs for constructing curl `-F` lines manually

I can't find any other way to attach files to a raw multipart form curl on the web. The closest is:

https://gist.github.com/z11i/fdd874573fc4956c3ee3aad164eddbfe

[Curl allows reading from stdin](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) via `-` and bash provides the builtin file `/dev/stdin`, so it might be possible to use a heredoc to pass in the `--data--raw` portion of Chrome's snippet as a file. Then more parameters could be passed in through a second json file or something. The closest I got was this **broken** example:

```
{
cat << 'EOF'
------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r\n..
EOF
} | curl <url> \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
  -F "file=@/dev/stdin;type=multipart/form-data"
```